# Simple program for C#

Tags: c#

I need help in a program that we had for a activity, the output should be

```
Enter number of quizzes:**3**
Quiz 1:80
Quiz 2:80
Quiz 3:80
Total:240
Avg:80
```

//The number of quizzes is user defined
Here's the code that my group mates made

```
console.Write("Enter the number of quizzes:");    
int x=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int loop=1;
int total;
int avg;
do
 {
 Console.Write(Quiz:+x:);
   int quiz=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  }
   while(x<=loop);
   total=total+quiz;
 Console.Write("Total"+total);
 Console.ReadLine();
 avg=(total)/3;
 Console.Write("Avg:"+avg);
 Console.ReadLine();
```

---

We can't seem to come up with the right codes for the program,sooo I'm hoping you guys could help us

Comment: I can see that you are getting some errors. For instance your `int.Parse` will fail in the do/while loop if you are expecting input like `1:80` - that isn't an int

Comment: @rhughes its just formatted weird, Quiz 1 is 80, not Quiz 1:80

Comment: We need to get the total of the quizzes w/o using arrays that's what total=total+ quiz is for

Answer (score 3):

I'm not posting the code for you, because it's homework. Instead, I'm going to write pseudo-code to describe the problem, and then you can make an attempt to write code to implement it:

```
Ask user for quiz count
Set accumulator to 0
Set counter to 1 
repeat
  Prompt user for quiz entry for counter value
  Get Score From User
  Add to accumulator
  Increment counter
until counter = quiz count
Write out accumulator
Calculate average (accumulator / quiz count)
Write out average
Pause
```

Comment: +1. I think we all don't want to end up working with copy-paste programmers in future!

Comment: thanks,We'll try to make the code :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you need something to hold your values and to then iterate through it to populate it. After populating it you need to produce a total and average?

The core concept you are missing here is the use of an Array or List, I think that is enough of a hint without giving you a homework answer.

EDIT:
Given that you've now stated you are meant to do it without using an array, I'll offer some further assistance:

You are increasing your accumulator outside your loop, you should be doing that inside the loop.

You are capturing the number of items in `x` but have hard-coded the value of `3` when calculating your average.

Fix those and you will be closer to an answer.

Comment: There's no need for an array or list here (and the poster indicates in a comment posted after you answered that they aren't supposed to use an array). It's a simple accumulator/loop counter/division operation; there's no need to store the separate inputs at all. (Not downvoting; just pointing it out.)

Comment: True, it is easy enough to do without an array. I thought the homework may have been trying to introduce them to arrays. I guessed wrong.

Comment: Like I said, not downvoting. Actually, I think it was a good answer because it didn't just provide code; it just missed the intent of the question problem statement slightly. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite thanks, I really do appreciate constructive feedback. I've updated with some for the OP with problems in their code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best hint I can give you is that, if you can decide exactly what you want to do with the variables you have declared, that will really help you. Look over your code and see if all variables has been used as intended. Look at your loop. Look at your calculations. Also, you need to understand the concept of scope, one of your variables is declared in one scope but used in a different scope.